# A java script program product list

Tags: javascript

pretty much stuck in this question(If value is above 10 than add that first multiply the value with 10 and than substract the value with 10 and multiply with the price and than add them both)
program as below Product Price Object: { 1-10: 10, 11-50: 9, 51-100: 8, 100+: 7 }

```
Input: Quantity Output Calculate based on price object qty e.g
 qty: 9 = 9*10 = 90 
qty: 11 = (10*10) + (1*9) = 109
qty: 50 = (10*10) + (40*9) = 460
```

Can there be optimized way of performing this

`

```
 qty= 0;
    const ten = 10;
    if(qty<=ten && qty>=1){
       console.log(qty*10)
     }
    else if(qty<=50 && qty>=11){
       console.log(((ten * ten)+((qty-ten)*9)))
     }
     else if(qty<=100 && qty>=51){
       console.log(((ten * ten)+((qty-ten)*8)))
     }
     else if(qty>=100){
       console.log(((ten * ten)+((qty-ten)*7)))
     }
     else{
       console.log("invalid value")
     }
```

`

Comment: No it is working but the line of code is more so i am finding an optimized solution for this

Comment: [Duplicate](//google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+check+number+against+multiple+ranges) of [Fastest way to compare a number to a list of numbers in a range?](/q/51866062/4642212). There are a few approaches there.